# In the ZF Axiom Schema of Specification, why can the selection criteria not refer to the subset to be specified?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

In the ZF Axiom Schema of Specification, why can the selection criteria not refer to the subset to be specified?

What inconsistencies if any would result from lifting of this restriction?

Answer (score 3):

From:

> $\forall A \ \exists B \ \forall x \ [x \in B \leftrightarrow (x \in A \land \varphi(x))]$

if we can have $\varphi(x,B)$, we can use e.g. $\lnot (x \in B)$.

Thus, considering $A= \{ \emptyset \}$, we would have:

> $\exists B \ \forall x \ [x \in B \leftrightarrow (x \in A \land \lnot (x \in B))]$.

Instantiating $x$ with $\emptyset$, we get:

> $\exists B \ [\emptyset \in B \leftrightarrow (\emptyset \in A \land \lnot (\emptyset \in B))]$.

But we know that $\emptyset \in A$, and thus:

> > $\exists B \ [\emptyset \in B \leftrightarrow \lnot (\emptyset \in B)]$.

Comment: Similarly, you could "prove" that all sets are empty. Could we not somehow strengthen the restriction to disallow a selection criteria that includes $x\notin B$ but allow some references to $B$?

Comment: @DanChristensen - the above is an example aimed at showing that allowing some sort of "self-referentiality" causes harm. Maybe we can find others...

Comment: But must we ban all self-referentiality here?

Comment: The self-reference can be more indirect. Consider $\phi \equiv (\forall C)[(\forall z \in A)[z \in B \leftrightarrow z \not \in C] \to x \in C]$. Then, if we can apply comprehension to $\phi$ to produce a set $B$, we can form $C = A \setminus B$ by normal comprehension, and then we can deduce $(\forall x \in A)[x \in B \leftrightarrow x \in C]$ which is impossible.  So, although you could include "some" additional instances of comprehension, beyond the ones normally allowed, there is no clearly visible syntactic class of those instances that would be consistent.

Comment: @CarlMummert Note that there **is** an instance of "$\not\in B$" in your sentence, hidden by the "$\iff$" - so if we restrict attention to sentences whose only Boolean operations are $\wedge,\vee,\neg$ and in which "$\not\in B$" doesn't appear, we might get something interesting.

Comment: @Noah: this is true, but we may need to look at at some more general sense of positive occurrences of $B$. E.g. someone could try to avoid the new restriction by writing $x \not \in B$ as $\lnot(x = x \land x \in B)$ (or replace $x = x$ with any valid statement or with an axiom of ZFC).  There are various senses of "occurring positively" in proof theory, but I am not sure if any of them is what we would want.

Comment: @CarlMummert I don't really see that this is a difficult task: just demand that the formula in question only contain negations applied to atomic formulas (which is no restriction at all), and then demand that we don't see any "$\not\in B$"s. Is there a problem, or unnaturality, with this attempt?

Comment: @Noah: I see - is there a short proof that those comprehension axioms are consistent?  I am not sure about the quantifiers.

Comment: @CarlMummert Oh, I've no reason at all to believe it's consistent - I just think it might be an interesting thing to look at, and I can't at the moment cook up a counterexample.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Take any prenex DNF $φ$ with positive self-membership in the 2nd parameter. $f = ( S ↦ S ∪ \{ x : x∈A ∧ φ(x,S) \} )$ is monotonic and has a fixed-point $T = \bigcup_{k∈ω} f^k(∅)$. For every $x∈A$: (1) if $φ(x,T)$, then $x∈f(T)=T$; (2) if $x∈T$, then $x∈f^{k+1}(∅)$ for some least $k∈ω$, so $φ(x,f^k(∅))$ and hence $φ(x,T)$. Therefore $T$ satisfies the desired property $∀x\ ( x∈T ⇔ x∈A ∧ φ(x,T) )$. No extra power gained over ZFC, and it is also useless for inductive definitions (which require "$x∈T ⇒ ∃y∈T\ ( ... )$").

Comment: @CarlMummert: If we require prenex form, it should be fine as per my above comment. If quantifiers can be negated, then $S = \{ x : x∈\{0\} ∧ ¬∀y ( x∈S ) \}$ yields an immediate contradiction. Right?

Comment: @NoahSchweber: I just realized; I was using (in my proof) the definition of "positive" where "$B$" only occurs in the form "$v∈B$", so no "$v=B$" or "$B∈v$" allowed either. My proof relies on my notion, but I can't find a contradiction if we only forbid "$¬v∈B$" and "$v=B$" and "$¬v=B$"...

Answer (score 2):

Fix a set $A$, parameters $\overline{c}$, and a formula $\varphi(x, y, \overline{z})$. We can think of this as defining an operator $\mathfrak{O}$ on the powerset of $A$: $$\mathfrak{O}(B)=\{a\in A:\varphi(a, B, \overline{c})\}.$$ The kinds of sentences you're interested in, then, are those asserting that $\mathfrak{O}$ has a fixed point.

In general this is impossible (e.g. as Mauro pointed out, take $\varphi(x, y)\iff x\not\in y$), but things get interesting if we restrict attention to formulas with appropriate "dynamic" properties. For example, whenever $\mathfrak{O}$ is monontonically increasing (resp. decreasing), it has a least (resp. greatest) fixed point. *(It obviously has a fixed point at all - namely, $A$ itself (resp. $\emptyset$) for trivial reasons.)*

So we can think in terms of fixed points (canonical or otherwise) for various kinds of inductive definitions. Especially when we work in systems much weaker than ZF, this can be very interesting: e.g. KP does not prove the existence of least fixed points for (even very simple) monontonically increasing inductive definitions (for example, every $\Pi^1_1$ set of natural numbers is inductively definable in $L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$, but e.g. $\mathcal{O}\not\in L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$). And indeed, inductive definability principles have turned out to be quite useful across logic - in proof theory, higher computability theory, etc.

However, ZF itself is more than strong enough to prove the existence of such fixed points, so I'm not aware of any strengthening of the separation scheme along these lines which is beyond ZF but not inconsistent with ZF.

---

EDIT: there is a reasonable candidate for a "universal" self-referential version of the Separation scheme. For $A,\overline{c},\varphi$ appropriate, say that a family $\mathcal{I}$ of subsets of $A$ is *sufficient for $A,\overline{c},\varphi$* if

- $\emptyset\in\mathcal{I}$, and
- for each $B\in\mathcal{I}$, we have $\{a: \varphi(a, B,\overline{c})\}\in \mathcal{I}$.

Then we can consider the axiom scheme consisting of each sentence of the form $$(*)_\varphi: \forall A,\overline{c}\mbox{ appropriate, there is a least set which is sufficient for $A,\overline{c},\varphi$}$$ for $\varphi$ an appropriate formula.

Note that each $(*)_\varphi$ is provable from ZFC (exercise), so this scheme is consistent with ZFC. However, it is also powerful enough to prove various inductive definability results: e.g. least fixed points of a monotonic operator is given by $\bigcup\mathcal{I}$ for $\mathcal{I}$ the least sufficient set for the appropriate $A,\overline{c},\varphi$. So over a weak theory, the scheme $\{(*)_\varphi:\varphi$ appropriate$\}$ can carry significant strength.

*Of course, there may be inductive definability principles which don't correspond to instances of the scheme above, "inductive definability principle" being a very broad idea.*